# Android Studio Error:java: Cannot find JDK '<unknown>' for module 'appcompat_v7'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a load of Android Eclipse projects which I need to get working on a new PC (old one broke).  Since Eclipse is now deprecated, I have installed Android Studio rather than Eclipse.

Both old and new PC run Ubuntu 14.04LTS, in case it's relevant.

After I import a project, Eclipse tells me "Error:java: Cannot find JDK '' for module 'appcompat_v7'".

I have tried installing Java 6 JDK (jdk1.6.0_45), Java 7 JDK (jdk1.7.0_79) and Java 8 JDK (jdk1.8.0_51) - no change.

--

Update:
After removing appcompat_v7 as a module, I hit two further problems:

1. I can't add it as a dependency.  I don't **have** a build.gradle, and if I right-click on my app project -> Open Module Settings -> Dependencies -> + -> Library, appcompat_v7 is not there to be selected.  SDK Manager reports that I have both Android Support Library and Android Support Repository installed.

...so I removed any reference to appcompat_v7 from my project and tried to run it without...

2. My project now also reports "Error:java: Cannot find JDK '' for module ''" -- just like it did for appcompat_v7.

Comment: Dont import app compat as a module. Use a gradle dependency.

Comment: how you was intergrade appcompat_v7 as library or jar in eclipse

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I don't completely understand what either of you mean, but I'm going to hack around with appcompat_v7 for a bit and see if I can get anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found out of this was not to import Eclipse projects into Android Studio at all - I had to do four, and all four of them gave similar problems.

Instead, just create a new Android Studio project and import the code, resources, XMLs and so on.  Fortunately all my projects were fairly small so this wasn't too difficult.